# How to auto advance a PowerPoint slide after an exit animation is over?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

PowerPoint entrance animation set up with "Start: With Previous" starts right when a new slide is advanced. However, if you set up an exit animation in the same way, it doesn't start with a slide ending sequence. Instead, the "Start: On Click" trigger needs to be used and **after your exit animation is over you still need one extra click just to advance to the next slide**.

**Workaround**s to this are obvious: create a duplicate slide, make your ending animations from the original slide being your starting animations on the duplicate slide and let them be followed with whatever you want or create a transition slide with those ending animations only and set up "Change Advance slide -> Automatically after -> [the time it takes your animations to finish]".

These workarounds will make it work for your audience, visually. However, it has an impact on slide numbers you might need to adjust accordingly and/or duplicate content changes. If you are the only one creating and using your presentation, this might be just fine. But if you are creating a presentation in collaborative mode with three other people and don't even know who will be the presenter at the end, you can mess things up.

Let's be specific: most of my slides have 0.2s fly in entrance animation applied to blocks of content coming from right, bottom or left. Advancing to the next slide I want them to fly out in another 0.2s exit animation being followed by new slide 0.2s fly in entrance animation of the new blocks. The *swapping of the blocks* should be triggered while advancing to the next slide, as usually.
As mentioned, I'm not able to achieve this without one extra click between the slides.

I wrote a **VBA script** that should start together with an exit animation and will auto advance a slide after 0.3s when the exit animation is over. That way I should get rid of those extra clicks which are needed right now.

```
Sub nextslide()
iTime = 0.3
Start = Timer
While Timer < Start + iTime
DoEvents
Wend
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .GotoSlide (ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex + 1)
End With
End Sub
```

It works well when binded on a box, button or another object. But I can't make it run on a single click *(anywhere on the slide)* so that it could start together with the exit animation onclick trigger. Creating a big transparent rectangular shape over the whole slide and binding the macro on it doesn't help either. By clicking it you only get the macro running, exit animation is not triggered.
Anyway, I don't want to bind the macro to any other workaround object but the slide itself.

Anyone knows **how to trigger a PowerPoint VBA script on slide onclick event?**
Anyone knows a secret **setting that will make the exit animation work as expected i.e. animating right before exiting a slide while transitioning to the next one?**
Anyone knows how to beat this dragon?

Thank you!

Comment: Your "workaround" involving the duplicate exit animation slides was just what I needed, thanks! If you did ever find a solution to your problem, you should post it as an answer here for future reference by others :)

Comment: You ever found a satisfactory solution to this? I mean, 10 years have passed, and several versions of powerpoint, it's hard to imagine that this is still not possible these days, right?

Comment: I went with the extra click for that particular presentation. It of course wasn't worth the hassle, and I started to approach my slides more practically – focusing more on the content. After all, if the content doesn't make sense, no transition effect would help the audience to understand it better. I realized I want the audience to remember something valuable, that would help them solve their problem, not a cool animation. As a result, never really looked back for a solution to this problem. Remember re-testing it some years later, still wasn't fixed. Not sure if MS considers this an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could also set the TRANSITIONS (tab) -> Advance Slide After 00:00:00 seconds.  You will need to set the SLIDESHOW (tab) to Use (Rehearsal) Timings.  This will automatically advance the slide after the last animation action.  You could, of course give it some seconds to wait, but it sounds like you just want to advance the slide.

Comment: Hi. Auto Advance Slide After 00:00:00 triggers both the Entry and Exit animations instantly and proceeds to the next slide right after that. Rehearsal timing only sets the Advance Slide After value based on how you proceed in the Rehearsal timing mode.

What I need is to enter a slide with a box flying in (Entry animation) and when I proceed to the next slide the box flies out (Exit animation) after which the slide is automatically changed to the next one where another box flies in (Entry animation on another slide), without me being forced to click twice for ex.animation and slide advance :-/

Comment: This was a good answer if it worked... -1.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept events in powerpoint using class module

In Class Module

In left combo (object) in VBA Explorer you can see ppt and in right your events

```
Private WithEvents ppt As PowerPoint.Application
```

In common module use

```
set x= new class1
```

Now you can use all events of presentation.

[]'s

Comment: eeh.. what? What is `x` supposed to do?

Comment: Perhaps, but there's no Slide OnClick event to trap, so in this case, I don't think this will be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OnSlideShowPageChange: VBA working while going to a slide without pressing any button

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = SSW.Presentation.Slides(x).SlideIndex Then
'PUT CODE HERE
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Theire is a code havy workaround
You do that using the duplicate methode. However you duplicate using vba not manualy.
You can use the OnSlideShowPageChange
Test if the slide is one that need to be duplicated using a naming scheme of your choice. Then duplicate the slide. Then set the trasition effect to non and make it transition after 0 sec duration. Then remove all animations and add the exit animations desired.
Then you use the SlideShowEnd event to delete all the duplicate slides.
Note that you can use the SlideShowBegin to duplicate all the slides at once however duplicating a slide is not a fast tasck. So if you have a lot of havy slides to duplicate strating you presentation may take few seconds.
Sorry for not providing the code since it needs several lines.
For naming the slides you use also a macro.